# Get User.Identity in WebApi from PublicAPI

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In my PublicAPI I have an Login API method where I do

```
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...)
```

I call this API method from my WebApi project. And then I get false for `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in WebApi. I suppose because it's a different instances.
But how can I use it then?
I'm using ASP.net Core Identity

UPD after question:
I have PublicApi it's a simple REST service. Also I have MVC .net approach with WebApi. Where I have controller for Login view. Then I call rest service from PublicApi to login

Comment: You're going to have to give us more details.  What is PublicAPI and how does it relate to WebApi?

Comment: How are you calling this WebApi? When you signin a user it attaches a cookie to the http response. You have to resend the cookie on the next request.

Comment: I have PublicApi it's a simple REST service.
Also I have MVC .net approach with WebApi. Where I have controller for Login view. Then I call rest service from PublicApi to login